# VB.NET: two form shows even one form hide

Tags: vb.net

I created a application that automatically show the **form** when **OPEN HOUR**. 
There are 3 form and 1 module. This are Form1, OpenForm, CloseForm and Module1.

PROBLEM: When its open hours, the CloseForm2 won't hide. 
I tried hide() and close(). Still not working.

Form1.vb

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.Visible = False
        Main()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Module1.vb

```
Module Module1
    Private WithEvents openTimer As New Timer()
    Private WithEvents closeTimer As New Timer()

    Sub Main()
        openTimer.Start()
        closeTimer.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub openTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles openTimer.Tick

        Dim currentTime As String = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm")
        Dim startTime As String = "08:33"
        Dim endTime As String = "08:35"

        If (currentTime >= startTime AndAlso currentTime <= endTime) Then
            Dim openForm As New OpenForm()
            Dim closeForm As New CloseForm()
            openForm.Show()
            closeForm.Hide()
            Form1.Hide()
            openTimer.Stop()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub closeTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles closeTimer.Tick

        Dim currentTime As String = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm")
        Dim startTime As String = "08:33"
        Dim endTime As String = "08:35"

        Form1.Label1.Text = currentTime
        Form1.Label2.Text = startTime
        Form1.Label3.Text = endTime

        If (currentTime < startTime OrElse currentTime > endTime) Then
            Dim closeForm As New CloseForm()
            Dim openForm As New OpenForm()
            closeForm.Show()
            openForm.Hide()
            Form1.Hide()
            closeTimer.Stop()
        End If
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Leave it to the cashier please, to open and close your app.  For the serious problems, consider creating a Windows Service or Scheduler Task. Side notes. 1) Compare the DateTimes as DateTimes not as strings.  2) Unless you open and close at the same time, the `endTime` should be at `20:33`. No? 3) You just need one instance of each Form, so don't keep creating new ones in the `Tick` events. 4) You just need one `Timer`.

Comment: I forgot to change the time. This was generated from CHATGPT.  I know its not clean, because I'll will clean the code once I resolve the problem.

Comment: Also, I was thinking for library application where the system will accessable in open hour.

Comment: But thanks you. No. 3 resolve the issue. 

Answer (score 1):

I created more instances of each Form in Tick events.

```
Dim closeForm As New CloseForm()
Dim openForm As New OpenForm()
```

This should be outside.

Comment: This fixes the core problem, but please also follow the hint about using just one timer. If such a small application is already that complex, you will loose the overview if things are getting bigger.